# Binding jQuery Autocomplete after Page Load

Tags: jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I have an input field on  my page to which I bind the jquery autocomplete. This works perfectly well for inputs that get rendered on the first page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".itemClass").autocomplete( {
source:foodItems
});
});
```

However , once I click on a button to add another row with the same input  an duse the same code again to bind the autocomplete; it doesn't work

```
   $scope.AddAnotherRow = function() {
    $scope.reviewList.push(new ItemReview(null,$scope.ratingOptions[0],null));
    jQuery(".itemClass").autocomplete({
       source:foodItems
        });
    $scope.totalComputed = false;
    };
```

I am using angular and the no. of rows is determined  by the items in an array . I am not getting any errors in the console , but the input fields added after the page load, donot exhibit the autocomplete behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add an event listener and call the function again.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".itemClass").autocomplete( {
      source:foodItems
      });

      $scope.AddAnotherRow = function() {
          $scope.reviewList.push(new ItemReview(null,$scope.ratingOptions[0],null));
          $scope.totalComputed = false;
      };


      $(".itemclass").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
          $(".itemClass").autocomplete( {
              source:foodItems
          });
      });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I am a bit of a novice with jquery. Can you elaborate a bit on this ? How do I go about implementing this ?

Comment: Well, your adding a row function works, right? But your autocomplete function works not for new rows? I would say you remove "jQuery(".itemClass").autocomplete({
       source:foodItems
        });" from your second function and add my function below your second function and with a bit luck it will work ;)

Comment: $scope.AddAnotherRow = function() {
$scope.reviewList.push(new ItemReview(null,$scope.ratingOptions[0],null));
$(".itemclass").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {      
    $(".itemClass").autocomplete({
        source: foodItems
    });   
});
DOMSubtreeModified();
$scope.totalComputed = false;
};                                                                    Now I get an error in the console that DOMSubtreeModified is not defined. It breaks here. A new row gets added tough

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified(); - that's not a function - where did you get that from? Wait I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Answer modified. I don't really know if your adding a row function works and what exactly it does but if it adds a row as expected then you should be able to use the code above

Comment: What function do I call again ?

Comment: Did you try the code above? That's all you need. You added DOMSubtreeModified(); to the code but that makes no sense

Comment: Yes I did try this code. It did not work. The AddAnotherRow() mnethod that gets called is defined in the controller file (a js file). And the document.ready function is defined in some other JS. Autocomplete works on inputs rendred on page load (coz of the document.ready code). A new row gets added due to the AddAnotherrOW() method. The code that you have suggested (binding an event)...wher do I add that ? and what function do I call again ?

Comment: Could you please add a js-fiddle or a link to your page? I need to see the complete sourcecode.

Comment: Could you solve it meanwhile? If not I would recommend to use just jQuery - here you can see how to add rows dynamically with jQuery: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/ With jQuery added rows the domtreemodified-Eventlistener should work

Comment: I understood your solution. I was not aware  that DOMSubtreeModified is also an event like say click.$(document).bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    $(".itemClass").autocomplete({
        source: foodItems
    }); I used document instead of itemClass . Coz my item text box (with class itemClass) is a part of the document. This works now. Thanks

Comment: But I am still wondering why it did not work with the original code

Comment: Well - at least it works now. I guess your code just worked for document ready - but with adding something to the domtree or after an ajax call you need those special event listeners. Thanks for accepting my answer btw!